# Ubuntu 16.04 takes too much time to boot and to shut down

Tags: boot, dual-boot, shutdown

After installing Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows10, it's taking too much time to boot and to shut down; approximately 2 minutes for each one.

I've been reading all the posts related to this problem on askubuntu and most of them indicates that swap's UUID is different from the actual UUID that is shown by using `sudo blkid`. So I checked and I found out that they matched perfectly.

Here is the output after typing `sudo systemd-analyze blame` in terminal

[image: Output after typing sudo systemd-analyze blame]

And here is the output after typing `sudo dmesg` in terminal

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_hOZGren_MPRlN5d0JkZ3BBeVE

I don't know what to do. Booting up and shutting down takes too much time on Ubuntu. But in Windows10, it boots up in 9-10 seconds and shuts down in 7-8 seconds.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Not Sure if this is a troll question or not but I will answer any way.

Any OS installed on a SSD will boot considerable faster then an HDD.

The simple answer is to install Ubuntu onto your SSD, and your boot times will decrease.

Another thing to be aware is that when windows 10 is shutdown using the shutdown command it doesn't actually shut down but goes into hibernation allowing it to be booted up considerable faster. (http://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/)

Comment: I know that any OS installed on an SSD will boot faster than an HDD, but Ubuntu is taking too much time. It appears a purple screen for 2 minutes, then goes black for 10 seconds and finally, I can log in with my password. I think this is too much time and it's not normal.